# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "registrarse"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

al momento de tratar de que se inserte los datos ingresados este me da el siguiente error, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "registrarse" in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\signin.php:82 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\signin.php on line 82

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST[registrarse])){
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $id = rand(1,99);
    
        $insertarDatos = "INSERT INTO signup VALUES ('$id', 
                                                    '$nombre', 
                                                    '$apellido', 
                                                    '$correo',
                                                    '$pass')";
    
        $ejecutarInsertar = mysqli_query($enlace, $insertarDatos);
    
        if(!$ejecutarInsertar){
          echo "Error en la linea de sql";
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: ponlo entre comillas: `$_POST['registrarse']` a ver si con eso ya superas ese error

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias :)